# Was Bernie selling out Caspar or not?

Tags: millers-crossing

The movies starts with Caspar accusing Bernie. The movie story is IMO so complex, I do not recall seeing scenes/clues for the answer and could not find via web search:

**Is there a moment when it becomes clear if Bernie was selling out Caspar or not?**